# How to enable textsearch in mongodb using python?

Tags: python, mongodb, jupyter-notebook

I have written `textSearchedEnabled=true` in the following script but a syntax error occurs. I can not understand how to enable the text search in mongo db using python.

```
 import json
 import pymongo # pip install pymongo
 from bson import json_util # Comes with pymongo
 from pymongo import MongoClient
 --setParameter textSearchEnabled=true
 client = pymongo.MongoClient('mongodb://user:user123@ds033499.mongolab.com:33499/enron')
 db = client.enron
 mbox = db.mbox

 # Create an index if it doesn't already exist
 mbox.ensure_index([("$**", "text")], name="TextIndex")

 # Get the collection stats (collstats) on a collection
 # named "mbox"
 print json.dumps(db.command("collstats", "mbox"), indent=1)

 # Use the db.command method to issue a "text" command
 # on collection "mbox" with parameters, remembering that
 # we need to use json_util to handle serialization of our JSON
 print json.dumps(db.command("text", "mbox",  
                        search="raptor", 
                        limit=1), 
             indent=1, default=json_util.default)
```

Comment: Well, the line `--setParameter textSearchEnabled=true` is not valid Python, so that might be part of your problem. Secondly, your code ends rather abruptly, with no `t` on `default` and no closing parenthesis `)`. Please [edit] your question to include your full code.

Comment: @MattDMo  how to enabled the textSearched

Comment: A simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/#q=mongodb+textSearchEnabled) will quickly lead you to the excellent MongoDB documentation. I suggest you read more about it there.

Answer (score 1):

Normally textSearch is enabled via the mongodb.conf or when starting mongodb. See: [Enable Text Search](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/enable-text-search/) documentation.

You can also run it via an admin command if the user has the admin rights:

```
client.admin.command('setParameter', textSearchEnabled=True)
```